# Real world total sales SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm fairly new to SQL and am having difficulty solving a problem.

'What are the total sales across all products for the salespeople that sell at least one unit of each of the five individual products with the highest sales by unit? Make sure that the query returns the total sales dollars in descending order. Only consider sales that take place over the six complete months prior to a @target_date parameter.'

3 tables exist in the DB.
SalesPerson (**SalesPersonID**,SalesYTD)
SalesOrderHeader (**SalesOrderID**,OrderDate,ShipDate)
SalesOrderDetail (**SalesOrderID**,**SalesOrderDetailID**,OrderQty,ProductID,UnitPrice)

This is where I'm at so far. I need to compile what I have into one statement and make necessary revisions. Please help!

To capture the top 5 highest sales by unit, the following SYNTAX should work:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, 
    SUM(Orderqty*Unitprice)   
FROM SalesOrderDetail  
GROUP BY ProductID  
WHERE Orderqty >=1 
  AND COUNT(productID) =5  
ORDER BY SUM(Orderqty*Unitprice) DESC  
LIMIT 5;
```

For the target_date parameter, I think it would be something along these lines?

```
SELECT 
    SalespersonID AS ‘Sales Representative’, 
    SalesYTD AS ‘Total Sales’, target_date  
FROM Salesperson  
WHERE target_date BETWEEN ‘01-DEC-13’ AND ’01-May-14’;
```

Comment: If the table descriptions are complete, then there is no connection from `SalesOrderDetail` to `SalesPerson`.

Comment: Assume it has a connection thru FK of SalesPersonID. Sorry - forgot to mention that.

Comment: I scaled the tables down to the necessary fields.

Answer (score 0):

For the top five highest sales, I would rather propose the slightly simplified

```sql
select productid, sum(orderqty * unitprice) as sales
from salesorderdetail
group by productid
order by sales desc
limit 5
```

and for the six months prior to `@target_date` something like

```sql
where orderdate between date_sub(@target_date, interval 6 months) and @target_date
```

---

Assuming a FK `SalesOrderDetail(SalesPersonID)`, you can then join the tables and top five sales as

```sql
select p.*
from salesperson p
join salesorderheader h on h.salespersionid = p.salespersionid
join salesorderdetail d on d.salesorderid = h.salesorderid
join (select productid, sum(orderqty * unitprice) as sales
      from salesorderdetail
      group by productid
      order by sales desc
      limit 5) t5 on t5.productid = d.productid
where h.orderdate between date_sub(@target_date, interval 6 months) and @target_date
order by p.salesytd desc
```